# Hide DIV until Google Adsense loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, adsense

I would like to hide/collapse the ad DIV with the `class="desk__ads"` until the ad is loaded.

Here's what I have so far to display the add:

```
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
```

The above code is added in the  section while the code below is added where I want to display the ad. I have 5 similar ads:

```
<div class="desk__ads">
  <ins class="adsbygoogle" style="display:inline-block;width:728px;height:90px" data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxx" data-ad-slot="xxxxxxxxxx"></ins>
  <script>
    (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
  </script>
</div>
```

I read that adding this code may work but I don't know where or how to add:

```
googletag.pubads().collapseEmptyDivs();
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: How about using onload="foo()" as an attribute inside the <script> tag

Comment: Could you post that as an answer with the complete code?